# Error reporting in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-reporting

am having trouble with reporting errors in zend framework, errors messages are not displayed on the browser and i recive error's like this:

> An error occurred
>
> Application error

However i already use those configuration in my application.ini file:

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1

phpSettings.display_errors = 1

phpSettings.track_errors = 1

phpSettings.error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: can you show us some code from your errorController?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The settings you are mentioning are php error management, whereas what you are looking for is really the Zend error and exception reporting. As kjy112 mentioned, it looks like Zend is defaulting to the production environment, which does not display any of the error reporting.

The Zend quickstart may be the fastest way to help get you up to speed on this:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.quick-start.html

Basically you can either set a define inside of your index.php file (not the cleanest), or I recommend setting it in your apache configuration and then reading it from your index.php file. I use something like this in my Bootstrap:

```
if (!defined('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    if (getenv('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT')) {
        define('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT', getenv('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT'));
    } else {
        define('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
    }
}
```

The default Zend error.phtml view has something akin to the following code, which blocks the display in the production environment:

```
<?php if ('production' !== $this->env): ?>
<div id="error">
    <p>
        <ul class="errorList">
            <li>
                <h3><?php echo $this->message ?></h3> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <h4>Exception information:</h4>
                <p><?php echo $this->exception->getMessage() ?></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h4>Stack trace:</h4>
                <p><?php echo $this->exception->getTraceAsString() ?></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h4>Request Parameters:</h4>
                <p><?php var_dump($this->request->getParams()) ?></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </p>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: yes there was an if statement that blocks the production environment

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem which has been eventually sorted out in 2 steps:

1.Open `{project name}/application/configs/application.ini` and at the end add the following lines:

```
[development : production]  
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
settings.debug.enabled = 1
```

2.Modify `{project name}/public/index.php`

```
<?php    
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH') || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Typically, you will also want to add your library/ directory
// to the include_path, particularly if it contains your ZF installed
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/library',
    get_include_path()
)));

/**
 * Zend_Application
 */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
$application->bootstrap()->run();

?>
```

Hopefully this will work for you as well.