# Zend Db Table when launch exception show the db user and password. How to stop it?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I use Zend_Db_Table to manage my MySQL connections. 
They works great, but there's just one HUGE security problem.

If there's an error, like MySQL is down, ZF throws an exception with the db connection username and password.

Here for example, I've set a wrong db password in my configuration.
This is the exception thrown.

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in /Users/claudiocanino/Dev/htdocs/include/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/claudiocanino/Dev/htdocs/include/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=ci...', 'root', 'rootads', Array)
#1 /Users/claudiocanino/Dev/htdocs/include/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#2 /Users/claudiocanino/Dev/htdocs/include/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
...
```

And here it is the username and password in clear.
How can I modify the Zend_Db_Table class so it don't show sensible informations into its exceptions?

Thanks

Comment: If you change to `production` environment, there is no stack trace shown. In fact, there is no exception shown at all, just what you define in your `ErrorController`/view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393040/error-reporting-in-zend-framework

Comment: Also check out the `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions` setting in your php.ini. If it is `1` (or non-zero) then the exception is shown regardless of the environment.

Comment: In my php.ini I've setted error_reporting = 0 and display_errors = Off. In the code there's also error_reporting(0); But it continues to show the same damn error. Do you have any idea? Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing display error options or production environment setting, you could define your ErrorController.

Having an ErrorController is almost mandatory for a project in a production system. It catches any exceptions thrown by your application due to a application logic flaw or it catches any URL that does not have any associated controllers/actions or does not match any pattern defined in your routers.

More details on setting up ErrorController for your Zend project - http://www.thedeveloperday.com/custom-profiler-for-live-environments/